# Why I'm Getting "Service web-cache lost on WCCP clinet" error on cisco router?

Tags: cisco, cache, squid

I'm configuring wccp and squid.

Here is wccp configuration or router:

```
ip wccp web-cache redirect-list wccp-access group-list wccp-server
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip wccp web-cache redirect in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip access-list standard wccp-server
 permit 10.10.10.2
!
ip access-list extended wccp-access
 deny   ip host 10.10.10.2 any
 permit tcp host 10.10.10.3 any eq www
 deny   ip any any
```

Here is squid configuration on ubuntu:

[image]

Also I set iptables configuration as below:

```
iptables -t nat -F PREROUTING
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wccp1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2:3128
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wccp1/rp_filter
```

Also GRE setup is as following:

```
iptunnel add wccp1 mode gre remote 101.10.10.1 local 10.10.10.2 dev ens33
ifconfig wccp1 up
ifconfig wccp1 10.10.10.2/32
```

But I'm Getting "Service web-cache lost on WCCP clinet 10.10.10.2" error on router.

How can I solve the problem??

Comment: Your GRE tunnel seems to be setup to 101.10.10.1 when it should be going to 10.10.10.1. Did you mistype in this post or on your server?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. it's just a typo in this post.